# How to deref @$_?

Tags: perl, parameters

I'm doing this:

```
sub worker {
    my ($job, @action) = @$_; #<-- error thrown here
    Build($job, @action[0]);
}


for (1..NUM_WORKERS) {
  async {
     while (defined(my $job = $q->dequeue())) {
        worker($job);
     }
  };
}

$q->enqueue([$_, 'clean']) for @compsCopy;

# When you're done adding to the queue.
$q->end();
$_->join() for threads->list();
```

When this executes, I get:

> Thread 8 terminated abnormally: Can't use string ("8") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use (@ the line referenced above)

What am I doing wrong here?

**edit:** To give more insight into what I'm trying to accomplish, I want to be able to do something like:

```
$q->enqueue([$_, 'clean']) for @compsCopy; #clean
$q->enqueue([$_, 'l1']) for @compsCopy; #build
$q->enqueue([$_, '']) for @compsCopy; #link
```

Where a user could specify when they're running the script, which `$action`s they want to perform on the components (directories).

Comment: does it work if you turn off use strict

Comment: @Jeef Turning off `strict` is a horrible idea. If something doesn't work with `strict`, you should fix the code, not turn off `strict`.

Comment: Why is the job type after the argument. Do you write `("Hello, World!")print;`

Comment: Why do you have two different things named `$job`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the first parameter to worker is an array reference, then you do the following:

```
sub worker {
    my ($job, @action) = @{$_[0]};
```

`$_` and `@_` may look similar but they are different variables.  Use the array `@_` for accessing the parameters passed to that subroutine.  `$_[0]` will hold the first element of that array.

Note: I'd advise that you come up with a different name for the first captured parameter to the `worker` sub.  Reusing `$job` is confusing.  Inside the sub it looks like `my ($val, @action) = ...` might be more semantically accurate.

---

Now, if we undo all the changes the OP made, we get back something that uses a saner parameter order and a doesn't use the name `$job` for two different things.

```
sub worker {
    my ($job) = @_;
    my ($job_type, @job_params) = @$job;

    if ($job_type eq 'clean') {
        clean(@job_params);
    }
    # elsif ($job_type eq '...') {
    #    ...
    # }
    # ...
}


for (1..NUM_WORKERS) {
  async {
     while (defined(my $job = $q->dequeue())) {
        worker($job);
     }
  };
}

$q->enqueue([ clean => $_ ]) for @compsCopy;

# When you're done adding to the queue.
$q->end();
$_->join() for threads->list();
```

Comment: So simple! Behind the scenes, how does this extract `$job` and `@action` from `@{$_[0]}`? What if I wanted to extract multiple parameters (e.g., if I called using `$q->enqueue([$_, 'clean', 'l1', '']) for @compsCopy;`?

Comment: Think of the first line as the same as, `my ($arrayref) = @_; my ($job, @action) = @$arrayref;`  Of course, this is assuming that your passed parameter really is an array reference.

Comment: Thank you - I've updated my question with more details.

Comment: That was a helpful update.  Updated my answer as well to provide more info and clarify my suggestion about your variable name choice.